# Stop hyperlink in TextBlock from opening browser

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I need to stop the Browser from opening when a Hyperlink is clicked inside a Textblock.
Here is the XAML:

```
<TextBlock Name="text" FontSize="40" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Here I Create the Hyperlink inside the Textblock:

```
link.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://google.de");
link.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "http://google.de" });
link.Click += link_Click;
text.Inlines.Add(link);
```

This is my link_Click function:

```
void link_Click(Hyperlink sender, HyperlinkClickEventArgs args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("print this instead of opening link in browser");
}
```

The text gets printed but the webbrowser opens too.
Any way to stop the browser from opening?

Comment: If you don't want it to open a browser window the why are you creating a hyperlink?

Comment: @Ben Robinson in the end I want to open it inside my application in a webview

Comment: Have you tried to remove *link.NavigateUri*?

Comment: @Romasz that Helped thanks. Can you write this as an Answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your *HyperLInk* to navigate (open the browser) then just remove [Hyperlink.NavigateUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.navigateuri(v=vs.105).aspx).